# Passing a struct pointer which contains an array as a parameter in C#

Tags: c#, pinvoke, dllimport

I have a function in C++ and exported in DLL.
the function is

```
LONG LOGIN(LPDEVINFO info);
```

the struct of `LPDEVINFO` is:

```
struct{  
       BYTE sSerialNumber[20];
} *LPDEVINFO;
```

to pass `LPDEVINFO` parameter, I have defined a class in managed code:

```
class DEVINFO{
     Byte[] sSerialNumber = new Byte[20];
}
```

and then P/Invoke like this:

```
[DllImport ('MyDll.dll')]
public static extern Int32 LOGIN(DEVINFO info);
```

and then call it in C#:

```
DEVINFO info = new DEVINFO();
Int id = LOGIN(info)
```

When I run this code, I got following error:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.AccessViolationException' occurred in WindowsFormsApplication1.exe

Additional information: Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.
```

I think the problem is caused by the array `sSerialNumber`. But I do not know how to define it in a right way.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If `LONG` is defined as a 64-bit integer type in C++, you'll have to either map export the function as `extern Int64 LOGIN(DEVINFO info);` or `extern long LOGIN(DEVINFO info);`. As for your `DEVINFO` class, I would make it a struct and apply the attribute `[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 20)]` to the byte array. [see this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1354275/marshaling-a-byte-array-to-a-c-sharp-structure)

Comment: @Jim `LONG` is 32 bit integer in C and C++ on Windows.

Comment: Ah, I've seen it redefined. I don't know why it would be, though.

Comment: @Jim It's a very common trap, `LONG` is the same as `LONG` and is 32 bits in C on Windows. In C# `long` is 64 bits.

Comment: Thanks @JimSchubert, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 20)] works for me.

Answer (score 3):

Use the `fixed` keyword to declare a struct that contains a fixed-size buffer:

```
public unsafe struct DevInfo
{
    public fixed byte sSerialNumber[20];
}
```

For more information, see [Fixed Size Buffers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zycewsya.aspx).

Also, to pass the struct by pointer (corresponding to `LPDEVINFO` on the native side), declare the function as follows:

```
[DllImport ('MyDll.dll')]
public static extern Int32 LOGIN(ref DevInfo info);
```

and call it:

```
DevInfo info = new DevInfo();
int id = LOGIN(ref info)
```

Comment: with keyword "fixed", I get the error CS0214: Pointers and fixed size buffers may only be used in an unsafe context

Comment: @englefly You'll probably need to put `unsafe` in the struct declaration (amended my answer) and (maybe) in the code that uses it. You'll also need to enable unsafe code in the C# Project Properties.

Answer (score 3):

I would use `UmanagedType.ByValArray` here:

```
class DEVINFO {
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst=20)]
    public byte[] sSerialNumber;
}
```

Otherwise it all looks fine to me. In particular it is perfectly fine to do this with a `class` rather than a `struct`.

Comment: I'm puzzled by the downvote on this answer and the downvote on Bradley's answer. I can't see anything wrong with either of them. If there is something wrong I'd like to correct it.

Answer (score 0):

The function is expecting a pointer to a structure, not the actual structure.

Use the Marshal.StructureToPtr() function to convert your structure to an IntPtr.

Example in C#:

```
[DllImport("MyDll.dll")]
public static extern Int32 LOGIN(IntPtr info);

...

DEVINFO info = new DEVINFO();
IntPtr infoPtr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf(info));
Marshal.StructureToPtr(info, infoPtr, false);
LOGIN(infoPtr);
```

If this is an OUT parameter, that is you need to read from it after the function is called since it is modified by the callee, then you use the Marshal.PtrToStructure to read it back into a managed structure like follows:

```
DEVINFO info = (DEVINFO)Marshal.PtrToStructure(infoPtr, typeof(DEVINFO));
```

Comment: Using `class` rather than struct, as per the code in the question means that a pointer will be passed. That's not the problem.

Comment: Bradley's answer is better.  I'm just used to using StructureToPtr for weird interop scenarios, like pointers to arrays of pointers to structs, where the simple ref functionality did not suffice.

Comment: Using `class` is just fine. I do it all the time.

Comment: And the point is this fact makes the entire content of your answer invalid.