# Pass array of struct to C from C# via struct pointer

Tags: c#, arrays, c, struct, pinvoke

I want to pass an array of struct from C# to C dll.

The struct definition in C:

```
typedef struct{
    BYTE name[32];
    DWORD age;
}DATA;
```

I marshalled the struct as follow:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct DATA
{
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 32)]
    public byte[] name;
    public int age;
}
```

The C function definition that I want to pass on:

```
void test_data(DATA * pStruct, DWORD length){
    _tprintf("test start\n");
    
    if (!pData)
    {
        _tprintf("pData is NULL\n");
    }
    unsigned int i,j;
    
    for(i = 0; i < length; i++){
        _tprintf("name: ");
        for(j = 0; j < 32; j++){
            _tprintf("%x ",pData[i].name[j]);
        }
        _tprintf("\n");
        _tprintf("age: %d",pData[i].age);
        _tprintf("\n");
    }

    _tprintf("test finish\n");
}
```

The function signature in C#:

```
[DllImport("a.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern void test_data(ref DATA pData, int length);
```

The setup in C#:

```
int length = 10;
DATA[] arr = new DATA[length];
for(int i = 0; i < length; i++){
  arr[i].name = new byte[32];
  arr[i].age = 10;
}

test_data(ref arr[0], length);
```

But I got these output:

```
test start
name: 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
age: 10
name: 7c 67 9a 2 a 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 2 0 0 0 eb 9 77 67 a4 eb 8f 0 0 0 0 0 2 0 0 0
age: 43673448
test finish
```

The first one is correct, but the second one seems weird, and I think there is something wrong with how I passed the reference or doing the setup.

I was inspired from the pinvoke web in SCardTransmit function [here](https://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/winscard.SCardTransmit) where it passed the byte array in C# to the `byte *` in C using `ref rapdu[0]`

How to correctly do this ?

Comment: A web search on `c# "MarshalAs" byte array`, we get [amongst others]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1354275/marshaling-a-byte-array-to-a-c-sharp-structure At a guess, from that: `public byte[] name;` --> `public byte[] name[32];` ?

Comment: @CraigEstey That's not how you declare an array in C#. If you wanted to declare a fixed size buffer, you seem to be missing the `fixed` keyword, but that also means declaring your structure as unsafe.

Comment: You show are you create your array of `DATA`, but not how you create the individual `DATA` objects in the array. I'm particularly interested in how you initialise `name`.

Comment: @EtiennedeMartel Yes (hence "guess"). The link has the correct syntax? So, would it be: `[FieldOffset(0x00)]
        public fixed byte name[32];`

Comment: @CraigEstey It's also unnecessary: the linked question is specifically about overlapping fields of reference type, which is forbidden. This should not be needed here, [as the documentation states](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/interop/default-marshalling-for-arrays#arrays-within-structures).

Comment: @EtiennedeMartel hi thx for commenting, I updated my post. I was able to get pass the error, I was wrong with the array initialization error, but now I got new problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not how you marshal an array of structures from managed code to native code.

In your P/Invoke declaration:

```
[DllImport("a.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern void test_data(ref DATA pData, int length);
```

`ref DATA pData` marshals to a pointer to a single `DATA` object. There is no guarantee that the rest of the array will be sent along with it. It *could* have worked if your structure was [blittable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/interop/blittable-and-non-blittable-types), because then marshalling it would simply have involved pinning the array and then passing its address as is to the C function. But, alas, the structure contains an array, which is a reference type. When you pass it to the C function, the marshaler has to do a copy to get a struct with the right layout. So, when you pass `ref arr[0]`, you're only sending one copy, and then your C code walks right off the end of the buffer and you hit undefined behaviour. And, on a more philosophical level, it's also less clear that `pData` is supposed to be an array.

So instead, to send the whole batch, just declare your argument as an array, [as explained in the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/interop/marshalling-different-types-of-arrays), and the marshaler will do the rest:

```
[DllImport("a.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern void test_data(DATA[] pData, int length);
```